# Calling a method using an array in java

Tags: java

I am trying to call the sort method in my main and I cannot figure out how to do it correctly.

```
public static void sortVehicles(Vehicle[] vehicles)
{
    Arrays.sort(vehicles);
    for(int i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(vehicles[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

I was doing this.....

```
public class 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Vehicle[] vehicles = fillArray(args[0]);

        vehicles = fillArray(args[1]);

        System.out.print("Enter 1 to print all of the files.\nEnter 2 to sort the files by email and print.\nEnter 3 to print the amount of files.\nEnter 4 to print only bike and truck files.\nEnter 5 to print only area codes (987).\nEnter number: ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x = input.nextInt();

        while (true) {
            if (x == 1) {
                printAll(vehicles);
            } else if (x == 2) {
                sortVehicles(vehicles);
            } else if (x == 3) {
                printRecordNumber(vehicles);
            } else if (x == 4) {
                printBicyclesAndTrucks(vehicles);
            } else if (x == 5) {
                printByAreaCode(vehicles);
            }
        }

    }// end main
```

It gives me an error that says it does not recognize the symbol of the sortVehicle

Comment: Where is the `sortVehicles` method declared?

Comment: Your class doesn't have a name.

Comment: Consider using an IDE.

Comment: I'd recommend using a Try Catch block instead of having your main throw an exception, as well

Comment: I got it working thanks! I was calling it from the class it was declared.

Answer (score 4):

If these two functions are not in the same class (or the class in which `sortVehicles` is declared is not a superclass of the one where this `main` method is declared), you will need to specify the name of the class in which `sortVehicles` is declared when calling the `sortVehicles` method, thusly:

```
VehicleSorter.sortVehicles(vehicles)
```

Alternatively, you may statically import the `sortVehicles` method in the class with your `main` method:

```
import static com.example.VehicleSorter.sortVehicles;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can make main in your `Vehicle` class.

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Vehicle[] vehicles = fillArray(args[0]);

    vehicles = fillArray(args[1]);

    System.out.print("Enter 1 to print all of the files.\nEnter 2 to sort the files by email and print.\nEnter 3 to print the amount of files.\nEnter 4 to print only bike and truck files.\nEnter 5 to print only area codes (987).\nEnter number: ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = input.nextInt();

    while (true) {
        if (x == 1) {
            printAll(vehicles);
        } else if (x == 2) {
            sortVehicles(vehicles);
        } else if (x == 3) {
            printRecordNumber(vehicles);
        } else if (x == 4) {
            printBicyclesAndTrucks(vehicles);
        } else if (x == 5) {
            printByAreaCode(vehicles);
        }
    }

}// end main

public static void sortVehicles(Vehicle[] vehicles)
{
    Arrays.sort(vehicles);
    for(int i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(vehicles[i]);
    }
    return;
}

}
```

Comment: `sortVehicles` is static, therefore in this case creation of `Vehicle` is reduntant.

Answer (score 0):

- static methods should be called with  **`<class name>.<function name>`**  e.g. `Math.max(int , int)`.

So here in your case it should be:

```
<Class name to which sortVehicles belongs>.sortVehicles(vehicles)
```

---

- else put the static method inside the class to which main method belongs:

  public class 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          Vehicle[] vehicles = fillArray(args[0]);

  ```
      vehicles = fillArray(args[1]);

      System.out.print("Enter 1 to print all of the files.\nEnter 2 to sort the files by email and print.\nEnter 3 to print the amount of files.\nEnter 4 to print only bike and truck files.\nEnter 5 to print only area codes (987).\nEnter number: ");

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      int x = input.nextInt();

      while (true) {
          if (x == 1) {
              printAll(vehicles);
          } else if (x == 2) {
              sortVehicles(vehicles);
          } else if (x == 3) {
              printRecordNumber(vehicles);
          } else if (x == 4) {
              printBicyclesAndTrucks(vehicles);
          } else if (x == 5) {
              printByAreaCode(vehicles);
          }
      }

  }
  public static void sortVehicles(Vehicle[] vehicles)
  {
      Arrays.sort(vehicles);
      for(int i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++)
      {
           System.out.println(vehicles[i]);
      }
      return;
  }

  }
  ```